# Downloading and saving files with AIR for iOs

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3, ipad, air

For a project we need to download and save pdf files on an IPAD device for offline use through an AIR for iOs application. 
After a lot of searching I haven't found much information on this subject. My question is, can it be done, and if so, can you provide us with some pointers to lead us in the right direction.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, first you check if you can access the web - can use a class like `air.net.URLMonitor`, if you can you can set up a `URLStream` instance.

You get data while its downloading the file using the progress event, write that out to a File instance using the `FileStream` class.

To display the PDF file you can use a `StageWebView` or `HTMLLoader`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Peter, is it possible to save these pdf's to your device so the air app can open them locally while being offline?